# ComboPooledDataSource not reusing connections

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services

As it says in the title my ComboPooledDataSource creates a new DB connection each request and never reuses or releases the connections. I call close() on the PreparedStatements, ResultSets, and Connection beforehand. I am using Tomcat and Amazon AWS Elastic Beanstalk and RDS. The relevant code is below:

Database class:

```
public class DB {

ComboPooledDataSource dataSource;

public static DB db = new DB();

private DB(){
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    try {
        dataSource.setDriverClass("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        String db = System.getProperty("RDS_DB_NAME");
        String username = System.getProperty("RDS_USERNAME");
        String password = System.getProperty("RDS_PASSWORD");
        String hostname = System.getProperty("RDS_HOSTNAME");
        String port = System.getProperty("RDS_PORT");

        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/" + db + "?user=" + username + "&password=" + password;

        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(jdbcURL);

        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Get database name
 * @return Databse name
 */
public static String dbN(){
    return DATABASE;
}

/**
 * Gets the database connection
 * @return Database connection
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public Connection getDatabase() throws SQLException{
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}}
```

API with DB call

```
@GET
@Path("/{session}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getAll(@PathParam("session") String session){

    JSONArray response = new JSONArray();
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement prepared = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        conn = DB.db.getDatabase();
        prepared = conn.prepareStatement("SQL STATEMENT");
        prepared.setString(1, session);
        prepared.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(Time.current()));

        rs = prepared.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("id", rs.getInt("id"));
            obj.put("name", rs.getString("name"));
            obj.put("color", rs.getString("color"));

            response.put(obj);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(500).build();
    } finally{
        try{
            prepared.close();
            rs.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return Response.status(200).entity(response.toString()).build();
}
```

I have been researching and have not found a solution that works. I know that it is definitely calling conn.close() and all the other functions, but none of them are actually being closed. Im all out of ideas, does anyone know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching ComboPooledDataSource and creating my own basic pool and connection wrapper. The connection wrapper wraps the Connection class, only replacing the close() and isClosed() functions with a boolean. The pool just held many of those and looked for closed ones when retrieving a connection, or closing them if there were too many open.